# Forgot password. What to do?

Tags: password, locked-out

I recently forgot my password on my perfectly working Motorola phone. I tried everything but nothing worked.

What  should I do?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I'd suggest starting with our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which is specifically for that :)

Comment: Did you forget the lockscreen password or your google password? I'm assuming the former, but just making sure. And if the first, have you enabled the Android Device Manager?

Comment: "*I tried everything but nothing worked*" -- that's a lie! 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) **Did you thoroughly search/research for an answer before asking your question?**  Tell us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far and why it didn't meet your needs? This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself and it saves us from reiterating obvious answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the below steps if you forgot lock screen password.**

1. Enter a wrong lock screen pattern five times (shouldn’t be hard if
   you don’t remember the correct one)
2. Select ‘Forgot Pattern’
3. Now you should be able to enter a backup PIN or your Google account
   login.
4. Enter either your backup PIN or your Google login.
5. Your phone should now be unlocked.

**You can also follow Device Manager by Android steps**

1. On a computer or other mobile phone, visit: 
   [google.com/android/devicemanager](http://google.com/android/devicemanager)
2. Sign in using your Google login details that you also used on your
   locked phone.
3. In the ADM interface, select the device you need to unlock (if it
   isn’t already selected).
4. Select ‘Lock’
5. In the appearing window, enter a temporary password. You don’t have
   to enter a recovery message. Now click ‘Lock’ again.
6. If it was successful, you should see a confirmation below the box
   with the buttons Ring, Lock and Erase.
7. On your phone you should now see a password field in which you
   should enter the temporary password. This should unlock your phone.
8. Now, before you go on with your life, go to your phone’s lock screen
   settings and disable the temporary password.
9. That’s it!

Comment: I tried doing that, however I was not able to unlock back my device through ADM, only lock it.